# Sending multicast push messages

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, push, google-cloud-messaging, multicast

I have a Facebook page with 3000 followers. It is necessary that these users get a push notification when I post something on Facebook with my page because the information I post is useless after some hours. This should happen in less then 5 minutes to all followers, of course only if they got my app.

1. Is it possible to realize this with the Facebook android SDK only? 
   I haven't found any possbility and I don't think this is possible at all.
2. I have 2 other scenarios to realize this:

   - A SQL database somewhere on the web, everytime a user installs and starts my app, it registers itself on the Google push service GCM and sends his registration-ID to my database where I store it. When I post something, I simply press a button on another app which only I have, this pulls all the registration-IDs of the database and sends the message to all of them. (I know that there is a limitation of 1000 users/message but splitting one message into 3 should not be a problem)
   - A backend server which offers multicast messages (at least 100 push messages/second). 
     This could work this way: A user installs and starts my app in which I have integrated a registration/login for the backend service, he logs into his account and sends his GCM key to the backend server, which stores them. Everytime I post something on facebook, I ask the backend service to send a push message to all registrated users.
     The problem is that I only found provider who concentrate on sending single push messages and limit them to about 20 push messages/second. I want it as simple and clean as possible for the user and an extra login/registration on an backend server would bloat my app.
     If there is a backend which offers everything I said it shouldn't cost more than ~5$/month, because the users should use my service for free.

Can these scenarions work?

To be honest, I don't think my two scenarios are that good. Is there any other option to realize what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first scenario may work very well, but I don't understand scenario two. From what I understand of it, the users do need to install another app in order to receive your Google Cloud Messages, it won't work with the Facebook app or something.

Here is a tutorial about 
[Making the Most of Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html)

Take a look at the [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) there is a lot to learn from it.

Using the Facebook SDK is an option if you start your app when you've posted the message on facebook. To get it all automated it's not the best solution. You can use [Python to fetch Facebook messages](http://fearofcoding.blogspot.nl/2012/10/python-script-to-fetch-messages-from.html) and then send a GCM request (or however it's called). [A GCM library for Python](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I added an explanation of my second scenario but I do prefer the first one. I'll have a look on your links but I'm not that good with python and I prefer using Java only.